# Exponential trend stationarity in GDP time series

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stochastic-processes, stationarity, trend

My economic textbook assumes that Gross Domestic Product is characterized by stationary deviations from a constant growth rate, reporting the following equation: $Y_t = Y_0(1+g)^t \exp(u_t)$, where $Y_t$ is GDP at time $t$, $Y_0$ is a constant, $g$ is the growth rate, and $u_t$ is a covariance stationary stochastic process.

However, the definition of a trend-stationary process is $Y_t = f(t) + u_t$, hence I expected the definition from the textbook to be something like $Y_t = Y_0(1+g)^t + u_t$. Conversely, from what I understand, according to the equation presented in the textbook, fluctuations from the trend caused by the error keep getting bigger over time, which is not what appens to real GDP time series (e.g. for a small $t$ the impact of the error is smaller than for a larger $t$).

Of course, taking the log of the first equation we end up with $\log(Y_t) = \log(Y_0) + t\log(1+g) + u_t$, which makes sense according to the definition I presented before. How can I reconcile these two facts?

Comment: The multiplicative nature of the model deals with the point that GDP is now much higher than it used to be, and if a 1% deviation from trend is as likely now as it used to be, then it will be a bigger absolute deviation now than then.  The logarithmic form deals with this (and for small $g$ you have $\log(1+g)\approx g$)